# Case insensitive active record query in rails-4

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Currently I am working on a project in rails 4 in which I have a user-page at example.com/username but it only finds the record if i use username in proper case, how can I perform case insensitive search in active record rails.
Check out my code below

```html
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username].downcase)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to use something similar to `where("username ILIKE ?")`. the `ILIKE` or similar syntax is dependant on your database though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
def self.search(query)
    where("lower(name) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{query}%") 
end
```

This would work in sqlite or in PostgreSQL.

Comment: The "%#{query}%" syntax matches any string containing the query value, which would work in many cases. However, if trying to match only exact case-insensitive values, this would be preferable/faster: `where("lower(name) = lower(?)", "#{query}")`.

Comment: Be aware that you're perhaps not using database indexes when you perform a function on a column value like this. Could be VERY slow. It does depend on your database and the nature of the index you create (e.g. ORACLE's function based indexes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arel Tables.

```
# Suppose the target username in DB is 'FooBAR'.
t = User.arel_table
@user = User.find_by(t[:username].matches 'foobar')
```

This will find users with usernames like 'FooBar', 'foobar', 'FOOBAR' and so on.

More details here: https://github.com/rails/arel.